# Confusion over pattern matching in Java

Tags: java, regex

So I am comparing strings with the following pattern:

```
"\"([a-zA-Z]*)\""
```

Am I right in thinking this means that it only allows for strings which have:

- Exactly one quotation mark at the beginning - \",
- Exactly one quotation mark at the end, - \" - and;
- Any number of either lower- or upper-case letters in between - ([a-zA-Z]*)

I ask this because that is what I have been led to believe after scouring both StackOverflow and the internet. But the matches() method is not throwing a PatternSyntaxException when I give it an empty string. What I mean by this is:

```
|""|  //This is valid or is meant to be

||    //This is invalid or is meant to be
```

Anyone care to enlighten me? For context this is in Java.

Edit: Hi all, the string I am matching with the regex does have quotes (I ask the user to enter a message surrounded by quotes). The code I am trying to write is:

```
if(!(components[MESSAGE].matches("^\\"([a-zA-Z]*)$\\"")))
            throw new InvalidSyntaxException("  > ERROR: Message must be surrounded by quotation marks.");
```

Where 'InvalidSyntaxException' is a custom exception class.

Some examples:

```
|""| - valid
||   - invalid (quotes required)
|"Example"| - valid
|"The year is 1995"| - invalid (no numbers)
```

SOLVED: You were all right - the only thing my code didn't do was allow spaces inside the message! That's why it kept complaining. Thanks again!

Comment: I'm not sure why you would think that `matches()` should throw an exception. It does that only on an invalid pattern, not if it doesn't match the string. Also any number includes none, so `""` is a valid match.

Comment: You need to inspect the `boolean` return value of `matches`, not expect an exception. The exception is thrown only if - as its name says - the syntax of the regex is bad. Your syntax looks fine.

Comment: @Gene, then what is the difference between bad syntax and syntax that fails? As in, from simply being 'false' as opposed to throwing an exception.

Comment: @DanielSoutar the syntax doesn't *fail*, your pattern simply does or doesn't match the string you are analyzing. Invalid syntax means the pattern you are using is not a valid regular expression.

Comment: A reg exp is like a text written in a language: if you don't respect the rules of that language, the reg exp is invalid (bad syntax that is); instead, if the pattern you wrote in your reg exp has no matching in the test string, then that's a reg exp that doesn't match

Comment: Can you provide some examples of valid and invalid messages?

Comment: So, what is the correct answer? No one could ever guess you need to match whitespaces.

Comment: Just use `matches("\"([a-zA-Z]*)\"")` as you propose at the start!  The question has changed. Now the regex has the `$` located so that to get a match you'd need a line break between the end of the text and the close quote.  And _don't_ double the backslashes \\. It's trying to match a backslash. And it's useless to put `^` and `$` in the regex to match begin and end of input. This method only returns `true` if the entire string matches.  Note that if your string has whitespace (e.g. newline) at beginning or end, the match will fail.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to remove the `"` at both ends of your regex:

```
\"([a-zA-Z]*)\"
```

I would suggest you to use [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/nWDdUd/1) to test your regex.

EDIT: As said in other answer, you need to compile the pattern before using it:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\"([a-zA-Z]*)\"")
if(!pattern.matches(components[MESSAGE]))
        throw new InvalidSyntaxException("  > ERROR: Message must be surrounded by quotation marks.");
```

Comment: Hi, I was wanting to include quotes!

Comment: Do you mean you want to match `"string"` or `""string""`?

Answer (score 1):

To assert `\"` in the end an start of the string, use `^` and `$`:

```
^\"([a-zA-Z]*)\"$
```

This should only find matches that start and end with `"`.

Comment: I'm afraid I tried that just now and nay luck! It still passes the test.

Comment: Also, wrapping THAT regex in quotes is throwing complaints from Java. The following line is invalid:

String regex = "^\\"([a-zA-Z]*)$\\"";

Comment: @DanielSoutar yeah that was a mistake

Comment: The `$` should go after the last `\"`

Comment: @watery I thought so but an online tester thought otherwise. tested then with java and forgot to edit answer

Answer (score 1):

So [PatternSyntaxException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/PatternSyntaxException.html) is thrown "to indicate a syntax error in a regular-expression pattern."  I don't expect you can get it by checking against an empty String.

Do you maybe have the arguments reversed?  (You haven't posted your code.)

You should pass your regex to `Patter.compile()`.  You then pass the string you want to check out to...

```
myPattern.matcher("my_string").matches();
```

Or if you're using `static boolean matches(String regex, CharSequence input)`, the regex pattern is first.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike the various parsing methods, `matches()` doesn't throw an exception if the input doesn't match the pattern, it simply returns `true` or `false`.

Use it like this:

```
if (input.matches("\"[a-zA-Z]*\""))
    // input is OK
```

Note that the brackets are unnecessary (as would be a leading `^` or a trailing `$` as they are implied with `matches()`).

Comment: Actually I was wanting to include quotes. So "" would be valid.

Comment: @dan OK then. See edited answer for what I think you're missing.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this code is helpful.

```
public class Foo {
  static void check(String s) {
    System.out.println("Match |" + s + "| = " 
        + Pattern.matches("\"([a-zA-Z]*)\"", s));
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    check("\"foo\""); // Should be true
    check("\"123\""); // Should be false
    check("\"\""); // should be true
    check("foo"); // Should be false
    check(""); // Should be false
  }
}
```

It prints

```
Match |"foo"| = true
Match |"123"| = false
Match |""| = true
Match |foo| = false
Match || = false
```